# juju charm push gives an error although charm gets pushed

Tags: juju

When i push my charm using below command i get the below error.

```
charm push . cs:~xyz/trusty/had-tx
ERROR cannot post archive: cannot unmarshal error response "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>502 Proxy Error</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Proxy Error</h1>\n<p>The proxy server received an invalid\r\nresponse from an upstream server.<br />\r\nThe proxy server could not handle the request <em><a href=\"/charmstore/v5/~xyz/trusty/had-tx/archive\">POST&nbsp;/charmstore/v5/~xyz/trusty/had-tx/archive</a></em>.<p>\nReason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at api.jujucharms.com Port 443</address>\n</body></html>\n": invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

Although the charm is pushed as i can see it in available charm `charm list`

Comment: Are you posting with a resource? Whats your `metadata.yaml` look like

Comment: Yes there is a resource. This issue popped up all of a sudden, didn't see it from quite long.

Comment: And now seeing it everytime I push the charm. Anybody knows the cause of it?

Comment: There is a fix going out in the charm command that will resolve this issue: https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/jujucharms.com/issues/332, It's currently waiting to release.

Comment: I see. Thanks for replying. Will it also impact the `juju deploy` command? Asking because my juju deploy also takes huge time.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if juju deploy is affected. I do know the fix is 2 part, first being a nicer error message in the charm client, and second some webserver fixes for the charmstore.

Comment: charm client issue might be this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800677/charm-fails-to-create-charm-store-client/41803892#41803892